# NiFi Confluent Schema Registry Exception

Tags: java, apache-nifi, confluent-schema-registry

We are trying to connect NiFi to our Confluent Kafka instance that has been set up to use the Confluent Schema Registry as we are publishing/consuming messages in the Avro format.

However, when we start up our NiFi kafka processor we get the following exception:

```
Failed to retrieve Schema with subjects array from any of the Confluent Schema Registry URL's 
provided; failure response message: User cannot access the resource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the security certs only granted us access to specific schema's in the Confluent Schema Registry.

Our certificates where missing the ability to query all the schema's. This is achieved by adding the `GLOBAL_SUBJECTS_READ` permission as per the Confluent [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/schema-registry/authorization/index.html#supported-operations).